# SQL results not making sense?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is for a school assignment. I don't understand why my SQL query is returning the number it is. I have 8 tables created. The main one of interest is Student

```
CREATE TABLE    Student
(
    Number  INT     NOT NULL    IDENTITY(130001, 1),
    Name    CHAR(55)    NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (Number)
)
```

And I've inserted 36 names into it (cause that's how many students we have). But when I run the query

```
SELECT COUNT(Student.Name) AS 'Total number of students'
FROM Student
```

It returns 144. I want to say it has something to do with the given code here.

```
DECLARE @totalProgram   INT
DECLARE @totalStudent   INT
DECLARE @i              INT

SET @totalProgram = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Program)
SET @totalStudent = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student)
SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= @totalStudent
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProgramGraduate
        (
            ProgramID, 
            StudentNumber
        )
        VALUES
        (
            FLOOR(RAND() * @totalProgram + 1),
            FLOOR(RAND() * @totalStudent + 130001)
        )
    SET @i = @i + 1
    END
GO
```

I think its purpose is to randomize the total number of students in a program? I understand the first 6 lines are declaring a variable and giving values for the variables, but when that WHILE loop begins, I get confused. If you feel like helping me dissect an understand what's going on in the code, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Hannah

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: This actually looks like SQL Server to me.

Comment: Sorry, yes. It's SQL Server.

Comment: How are you inserting rows into your student table?

Comment: INSERT INTO Student(Name) VALUES('Last, First')

Comment: If query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student` return 144 that mean that table have 144 rows.

Comment: You're right. I just did SELECT * FROM Student and it showed all of the information. I guess my question now is why does it not stop at 36 and why does it keep on going?

Comment: @HanH1113 This code can add one student in multiple Programmes,  and some students might not even get selected. Is this something you would want ??

Comment: This is the code that was given by the professor, so I guess it makes sense. The whole schema is that of a university and the corresponding courses and programs in that university. Some students could be enrolled in some courses and not in others. I suppose it makes sense, but could you help me understand how it works the way it does?

Comment: Which part of this code you are struggling with ?

Comment: The second code creates a new table and fills random values into the fields ProgramID and StudentNumber for every student in 
the student table. Importent to mention is u dont have a primKey and since the StudentNumber is random & rounded it is possible to have
the same number twice.

Comment: @MuhammedAli           
How did you know that some students would be selected into multiple programs and others wouldn't? I'm struggling with making sense of the
`FLOOR(RAND() * @totalProgram + 1),
            FLOOR(RAND() * @totalStudent + 130001)
        )
    SET @i = @i + 1  `

Comment: @HanH1113 Your Code will only Execute the number of time = Number of Row in your table. FLOOR(RAND() * totalStudent + 130001) ) Pick a random number between 130001 and value of totalStudent so if you dont get a hit on each student in totalStudent times your code will stop executing regardless of how many student are yet to be assigned to a program.

Comment: Floor = Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression. (from msdn)
Rand() = Returns a pseudo-random float value from 0 through 1, exclusive. (from msdn)
e.g. (at)totalStudent = 36 and (at)i  = 5.
The fifths entry for StudentNumber is (with a Random Number of 0,07).
Floor(0.47 * 36 + 130001) => Floor(327602.5) => 327602

Comment: @HanH1113 I have tried to explain your code step by step in the answer section please have a look

Comment: I did. It's very helpful. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Answer to your question " How did you know that some students would be selected into multiple programs and others wouldn't? " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 10 + 1) do this it will give you random number between 1 and 10 , but not distinct random number , run this query 10 times and see if you get a hit on all 10 number from 1 to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @totalProgram   INT   --<-- Declaration of variables
DECLARE @totalStudent   INT
DECLARE @i              INT

SET @totalProgram = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Program) --<-- @totalProgram storing total number of rows in Program table 
SET @totalStudent = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student) --<-- @totalStudent storing total number of rows in Student table 
SET @i = 1                                        --<-- Hardcoding value to 1

WHILE @i <= @totalStudent    --<-- "While loop Condition" Execute this while until value of @i is Less than or equal to the value of  @totalStudent
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProgramGraduate      --<-- Insert Statement for the ProgramGraduate table 
        (
            ProgramID,                 --<-- Column Name 1
            StudentNumber               --<-- Column Name 2
        )
        VALUES
        (
            FLOOR(RAND() * @totalProgram + 1),          --<-- Generating a Random Number Between 1 and @totalProgram
            FLOOR(RAND() * @totalStudent + 130001)      --<-- Generating a Random Number Between 130001 and @totalStudent 
        )
    SET @i = @i + 1    --<-- Increasing the value of @i by one everytime this loop executes "Eventually to make the while loop condition ture and break the loop otherwise it will be an idefinite loop"
    END
GO
```